# Ubuntu Server 14.04 stops responding

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-14.04

I have set up an Ubuntu server at home to host a small web-page containing files I want to access from outside. All is working really well but sometimes if I wake up, the server is frozen. I can't connect via SSH, HTTP, ... I have tried to plug in a keyboard and monitor but it only shows a black screen. So I have to reboot the machine and everything is working again.

```
The last lines of `/var/log/syslog` are:
Jan 22 10:15:01 server CRON[3708]: (www-data) CMD (php -f
/var/www/ownCloud/cron.php) Jan 22 10:15:01 server CRON[3710]: (user)
CMD (/home/user/cronjobs/cloudflare 1>>
/home/user/cronjobs/logs/cloudflare.out 2>>
/home/user/cronjobs/logs/cloudflare.err)   Jan 22 10:15:28 server
kernel: [244035.211772] [UFW BLOCK] IN=em1 OUT=
MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:9c:c7:a6:ba:7c:0f:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1
DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jan 22 11:23:10 server rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd"
swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="780" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start  
Jan 22 11:23:10 server rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104  
Jan 22 11:23:10 server rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

which means the server stopped responding between 10:15 and 11:23 (when I rebooted the machine). Any ideas how to solve or investigate the problem further?

Comment: I'd setup a (r)syslog server and have it send its logs there..

Comment: Is there any service which I can use or do I have to set up an own server somewhere? Do you think this will show more entries?

Comment: It's probably a hardware or driver issue. Since hardware is harder to swap in and out, you might try checking for driver updates, or downgrade to an older Linux distro if it's an older machine (newer distros were probably never tested on your older hardware). Also see if there's any optional boards installed that you can remove or whatever. These kinds of problems are always annoying to troubleshoot... good luck.

Comment: The hardware is not that old; it has an "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz" processor. If I recall correctly I had the same problem with older hardware I used before with an older ubuntu version.

Comment: Suggest moving this to askubuntu.com